# Conditional Formatting based on last date being greater than todays date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to highlight a blank cell with Red if the date in the preceeding cell is 2 days later than today's date.

For example

Cell G5 has the date something happened

Cell H5 is the next step in the process

If cell H5 is blank for 2 days past the date in G5 I want to highlight red but then once the date is entered into H5 I want the highlight to go away... or turn green

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Select cell H5 and define a custom CF rule based on a formula like so:

```
=AND(ISBLANK(H5), G5+2 <= TODAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Range you need to format, go to **Conditonal Formatting**- **New Rule**- **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**- enther the formulas:

1. Red: `=AND(H5="",(TODAY()-G5)<=2)`
2. Green: `=H5<>""`

[image]